# SwiftData insert Relationship large array

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data, swift-data

I'm trying to use SwiftData with a large amount of objects and it seems there is very bad performance when inserting items.

For example I have a child model that looks like below. Notice I didn't set explicitly the `@Relationship` macro, but I also tried it including `@Relationship(inverse: ...)`

I'm trying to insert more than 300,000 objects

```
@Model
class SomeChild {
    let title: String
    var parent: MyParent?
        
    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}
```

I have a parent model that looks like this:

```
@Model
class MyParent {
    let name: String
    var children: [SomeChild]?
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

```
final actor DBActor: ModelActor {

   let modelContainer: ModelContainer
   let modelExecutor: any ModelExecutor

    @MainActor
    init(modelContainer: ModelContainer) {
        self.modelContainer = modelContainer
        let context = ModelContext(modelContainer)
        context.undoManager = nil
        context.autosaveEnabled = false
        modelExecutor = DefaultSerialModelExecutor(modelContext: context)
    }

    func storeObjects() async throws {
        var bgContext = ModelContext(modelContainer)
        bgContext.undoManager = nil 
        bgContext.autosaveEnabled = false

        let parent = MyParent(name: "hello")
        bgContext.insert(parent)
        bgContext.save()

        let loader = MyLoader() // loads remote strings async

        var batch = [String]()

        for await someString in loader {
           batch.append(someString)

           if batch.count > 500 {
             for value in batch {
                let child = SomeChild(title: value)
                bgContext.insert(child)
                child.parent = parent // this causes major slowdowns
                //also tried parent.children?.append(child)
             }
             bgContext.save()
             batch = []
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Have 2 questions:

1. I would like the UI to remain responsive while saving the objects, so I'm running it part of a `Task { DBActor(modelContainer: myContainer).storeObjects() }` but I see the main thread hangs badly unless I comment out `child.parent = parent`, but I need this to easily find the parent. Any idea if it's a SwiftData specific issue? Because if I'm running it with Instruments I see when setting the relation, SwiftData creates a new `SomeChild(backingData:)` maybe that's the cause?
2. I tested how the SwiftUI app I have works with many SomeChild objects and I can see there is a delay when starting or doing stuff in the UI. I'm showing it using a `List()` and a `@Query var children: [SomeChild]`, I thought the `List()` would do some internal pagination, any one knows if there's an existing view for that or I have to somehow manually do it?

Thanks!

Comment: SwiftUI does little to pagination. For 300,000 objects I would use CoreData and UIKit. There is nothing like the Faulting of an NSFetchedResultsController. SwiftUI’s lazy loading is no comparison.

Comment: Did you try to append all children at once?

Comment: yes, when I append all at once there is also a delay which blocks the main thread because I still see SwiftData calls the @Model setter which does the `SomeChild(backingData:)` call , and also I wanted to make the List add partial results while continuing to append in the background

Comment: I agree with using Core Data directly, but there is no reason to throw out SwiftUI if you don't want to. You can use core data with SwiftUI. IMO SwiftData and its predecessor approach of putting queries directly in SwiftUI views are ok for "toy" apps but not great if you have to do more complex operations or have larger amounts of data.

Comment: I agree with @Paulw11 even though I didn't use SwiftData already for an intensive project, it seems that all the "simplifications" in SwiftData (which are good for simple apps) doesn't allow more complexe and fine things like in CoreData. Question : Is the autosave done in the main context? Could that be the reason?

Comment: I disabled autoSave in above code, I'm saving it manually after each batch of 500 items, but the UI lag happens anyway